# Doubt in build.xml file in Apache-Ant1.6.5

Tags: java

I have used Collections in my code with Generics. When try to compile that java file in build.xml, its showing error at generics and its saying its not a statement. I am using Apache-Ant-1.6.5 and  i have installed JDK 1.5 only . I know generic will support in jdk1.5 but its showing error. The below is the error i am getting for the code

code :

```
Map<String, String> inputconfigmap = 
    new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Exception :

```
compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\GenericPreProcessor\Source\classes
    [javac] Compiling 49 source files to D:\GenericPreProcessor\Source\classes
    [javac] D:\GenericPreProcessor\Source\src\com\dnb\genericpreprocessor\fileprocessor\FixedLength
FileProcessor.java:187: not a statement
    [javac] Map<String, String> inputconfigmap = 
                new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

---

I did as per your suggestion but i got the following in the console.

**Console :**
D:\GenericPreProcessor\Source>ant
Buildfile: build.xml
     [echo] JVM version is 1.5
     [echo] Target compilation is ${ant.build.javac.target}

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\GenericPreProcessor\Source\classes

cleanJar:

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\GenericPreProcessor\Source\classes
    [javac] Compiling 49 source files to D:\GenericPreProcessor\Source\classes
    [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.5
    [javac] Usage: javac  
    [javac] where possible options include:
    [javac]   -g                        Generate all debugging info
    [javac]   -g:none                   Generate no debugging info
    [javac]   -g:{lines,vars,source}    Generate only some debugging info
    [javac]   -nowarn                   Generate no warnings
    [javac]   -verbose                  Output messages about what the compiler is doing
    [javac]   -deprecation              Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
    [javac]   -classpath          Specify where to find user class files
    [javac]   -sourcepath         Specify where to find input source files
    [javac]   -bootclasspath      Override location of bootstrap class files
    [javac]   -extdirs            Override location of installed extensions
    [javac]   -d             Specify where to place generated class files
    [javac]   -encoding       Specify character encoding used by source files
    [javac]   -source          Provide source compatibility with specified release
    [javac]   -target          Generate class files for specific VM version
    [javac]   -help                     Print a synopsis of standard options

BUILD FAILED

Comment: should be edit to remove the extra brackets...

Comment: I don get which brackets you are telling... There is no problem in coding as it is running fine when i compile n run in eclipse.

Comment: look through the edit logs raja http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/520168/list

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried explicitly setting the `source` and `target` attributes for your [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task?

```
<target name="compile">
    <javac .....
        source="1.6"
        target="1.6" />
</target>
```

Comment: Sorry i dont get you. can you explain little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check the version of your compilator with :

```
<echo>JVM version is ${ant.java.version}</echo>
<echo>Target compilation is ${ant.build.javac.target}</echo>
```

And you can add `<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.5" />` to force the compiler to use Java 5 compliance...
This property is the default target from ant 1.7, for ant 1.6 I think you must add `target="${ant.build.javac.target}"` to your javac target.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the type of the Map, i.e:

```
Map<String, String> inputconfigmap  = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Map<?, ?> inputconfigmap = new LinkedHashMap<?, ?>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using double angle brackets (<< and >>)? They should be single ones as kgiannakakis showed:

```
Map<String, String> inputconfigmap  = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```